# g++ treats returned string literal as const char pointer not const char array

Tags: c++, g++, string-literals

I'm seeing some odd behaviour when returning a string literal from a function that should perform an implicit conversion with g++ (version 4.7.3).  Can anyone explain why the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

class Test
{
public:
  template <unsigned int N>
  Test(const char (&foo)[N])
  {
    printf("Template const char array constructor\n");
  }

  Test(char* foo)
  {
    printf("char* constructor\n");
  }
};

Test fn()
{
  return "foo";
}

int main()
{
  Test t("bar");
  Test u = fn();

  return 0;
}
```

produces the result:

```
Template const char array constructor
char* constructor
```

on g++?  The surprising thing being that the char* constructor is chosen in preference to the const char array constructor when generating the return value from fn().  Admittedly there is a warning, "deprecated conversion from string constant to 'char*'"

Even more surprisingly if you remove the char* constructor then the code doesn't compile with g++.

It works as expected with clang (Template constructor used both times), which makes me think this is a compiler bug, but maybe it's just a weird corner of the C++ spec - could anyone confirm?

Comment: Your compiling c++11, arent you?

Comment: @Paranaix I'm seeing this fail on GCC 4.8 in C++11 mode, so even if the OP isn't, that isn't the problem.

Comment: String literals aren't special here, except perhaps for the deprecated conversion to `char*`, it behaves the same way with other arrays too: `const char foo[4] = {}; return foo;` fails with "error: could not convert ‘(const char*)(& foo)’ from ‘const char*’ to ‘Test’"

Comment: The same applies to function references: they get converted to pointers, and any constructor that accepts a reference is not usable: `struct S { S(S(&)()); }; S f() { return f; }` is accepted by clang, but gcc reports "error: could not convert ‘f’ from ‘S (*)()’ to ‘S’" A workaround could be `return S(f);`, or in your example, `return Test("foo");`

Comment: @gwiazdorrr You mean "if", not "since", surely?

Comment: If you are on C++11, the easiest workaround is to `return { "foo" }`. (@hvd you are right)

Comment: @gwiazdorrr Unfortunately I need this to compile with VS2010, so can't use initializer lists.  I guess I'll have to live with saying `Test("foo")` in order to get this compiling with gcc, but I'd rather avoid the extra syntax.

Comment: Why are you using `printf` in C++?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It appears that this is a bug affecting several versions of gcc which has been reported over and over again, most recently about a month ago against the most recent version, 4.8.2. See http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=24666

Comment: +1 A workaround is to use an explicit conversion instead of an implicit one, i.e. `return Test( "foo" )`.

Comment: As of today (slightly different but possibly related: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=16333) this still stands

Answer (score 1):

If you want a reusable C++03 workaround (i.e. one in which you won't have to care about what the return type is, as long it is constructible from a char array), you will have to use some kind of a char array wrapper.

```
template <size_t N>
struct char_array_ref
{
    typedef const char (&ref_type)[N];
    ref_type ref;

    template <typename T>
    operator T() const
    {
        return T(ref);
    }
};

template <size_t N>
char_array_ref<N> stupid_gxx_use_array_reference(const char (&chars)[N])
{
    return char_array_ref<N> { chars };
}


Test fn()
{
  return stupid_gxx_use_array_reference("foo");
}
```

Should be easy to regex propagate this across your codebase, too.

Obviously, in your code you can change `stupid_gxx_use_array_reference` into something less verbose.