# Possible bug in GCC: literal string types in a structure

Tags: c++, gcc, c++11, string-literals

I am trying to write a C++ class whose constructor only accepts string literal and not other forms of strings. The goal is to cache the construction of custom string objects for literal strings, when we know the string content is constant during whole program execution. Here is my implementation:

```
class LiteralString
{
public:
    template <int N> LiteralString(const char (&str)[N]) : string(str) {}
    LiteralString(char* str) = delete;
    operator const char*() const { return string; }
private:
    const char* string;
};
```

It accepts `const char[N]`, but explicitly forbids `char[N]`, typically used in temporary buffers on stack. The constructor is implicit to transparently accept literal strings. Now consider a `LiteralString` inside a structure like in this example :

```
struct tTest
{
    LiteralString text;
};
static const tTest test = { "Foo" } ;
```

The small above snippet compiles successfully on Clang (Apple version 5.1) and on Visual Studio 2013. But GCC (version 4.8 for Android) fails to compile. GCC compiles however with an explicit `test = { LiteralString("Foo") }`.

My question is: is the above code valid C++11 ? In this case, there is probably a bug in GCC 4.8. Otherwise, Clang and VS compilers are too permissive.

Comment: Similar: [g++ treats returned string literal as const char pointer not const char array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22054382/g-treats-returned-string-literal-as-const-char-pointer-not-const-char-array)

Comment: Yes. It seems to be exactly my problem.

Answer (score 3):

> I am trying to write a C++ class whose constructor only accepts string literal and not other forms of strings.

This is impossible. There is no way to discriminate between sources of arrays of `const char`.

Comment: Harmless example [here](http://ideone.com/9RYyMI), though it gets the point across I would guess.

Comment: @Matthieu I know this is impossible. My goal is to refuse 99.9% of real life non-literal strings. The example above is artificial, I am not worried about it. What could be a real problem however is a `const char[] = {1, 2}` buffer on stack.